# How to store a user-filled HTML table in local storage and then display it in a different results HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, local-storage

Summary of my program:

1. Users **fill out** a HTML table (I'm not having problems with this step) in table.HTML page
2. HTML table is **stored** in localStorage (using `.SET` on table.**`innerHTML`**)
3. HTML table is **displayed** (using `.GET`) in a **different** results.HTML **page**

My attempt is below:

**(INSIDE TABLE.HTML PAGE) HTML TABLE DESIGN**

```
<div id="table-scroll">
<table class="content_table" double; id="tableStyle">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Criteria</th>
                    <th>✅</th>
                    <th>❌</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
    
            <tbody style="max-height: 50px; overflow-y: auto">
    
            <tr class="colspan_content">
                <td colspan="3">Details</td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr id="user_name">
                <td>Name</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>❌</td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr id="user_height">
                <td>Height</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>❌</td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr id="user_favourite_colour">
                <td>Colour</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>❌</td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr id="user_age">
                <td>Age</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>❌</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**(INSIDE TABLE.HTML PAGE) BUTTON WHICH, ON CLICK, WILL SAVE THE HTML DATA IN LOCAL STORAGE AND ADD IT TO THE RESULTS HTML PAGE**

```
    <button id="save_table" type="button">Click to save HTML data</button>
```

**(INSIDE RESULTS.HTML PAGE) RESULTS.HTML PAGE WHICH I WANT THE TABLE DATA FROM LOCAL STORAGE (FROM TABLE.HTML) TO BE ADDED TO**

```
<body>

    <p id="show_table_data"></p> //JS function saveTableData() used to display table here
    
</body>
```

**JS FILE USING LOCALSTORAGE `.GET` and `.SET`**

```
function saveTableData() {
    localStorage.setItem('table', document.getElementById('table-scroll').innerHTML);

    document.getElementById("show_table_data").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("table-scroll");
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('save_table').addEventListener("click", () => {
            saveTableData();
        });
      });
```

I've tried using the div element's `.innerHTML` attribute to try and store the table data in LocalStorage and subsequently display the table data from LocalStorage in a separate HTML page, but can't seem to get it to work! Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

**EDIT WITH BOTH FUNCTIONS:**

```
function saveTableData() {
    localStorage.setItem('table', document.getElementById('table-scroll').innerHTML);

}

function loadTableData() {
    document.getElementById("show_table_data").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("table");
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('save_table').addEventListener("click", () => {
            saveTableData();
        });
      });

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('save_table').addEventListener("click", () => {
            loadTableData();
        });
      });
```

Error I'm receiving: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
at loadTableData (script1.js:1138:58)
at HTMLButtonElement. (script1.js:1149:13)

Answer (score 1):

1. you have non-matching keys when you store table in local storage and when you query it:

storing:

```js
    localStorage.setItem('table', document.getElementById('table-scroll').innerHTML); // key is 'table'
```

retrieving:

```js
    document.getElementById("show_table_data").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("table-scroll"); // key is 'table-scroll'
```

2. you use the same function `saveTableData` to both store and retrieve the data on different pages. Current implementation can work on the first page (will store the data) but then will probably throw an error because `documetn.getElementById('show_table_datad')` will return `undefined` (there is no such table in `TABLE.HTML`. On `RESULTS.HTML`  this function won't be able to work because:

   1. there is no trigger for it.
   2. it should throw an error on `document.getElementById('table-scroll')` because this table exists on a different page.

You should split this into two functions: `saveTableData` and `loadTableData`.

Comment: Hey @purple - I made an edit in my original post and took on your advice. I split the original function into two functions, but for some reason I'm getting this error (which I've also included in the edit). Would you be able to shine some light on it?

Comment: Also @purple, would I add both functions on the same table.html page, or would I add the saveTableData() function to table.html and loadTableData() function to the results.html table?

Comment: You should only include functions you need on each page. `saveTableData` on `TABLE.HTML` and `loadTableData` on `RESULT.HTML`. You get the error because now the button on `TABLE.HTML` still tries to do both tasks: save the data and load the data. You need different buttons on different pages and assign different event handlers to them